# openni detecting device only in debug mode

Tags: ros, kinect, openni-node, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to run the openni_node.launch file on a PR2 with ubuntu lucid and diamondback.
When starting the launch file with "debug=true" the kinect is detected correctly and I can visualize its output in rviz.
However when starting the .launch with "debug=false", the node can't find the device.

The main difference with debug is that it launchs the node on a separate xterm. As far as I have seen, no environement variable is different in the xterm.

Someone has any idea ?

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11568/openni-detecting-device-only-in-debug-mode/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found out! This was due to another install of openni which was messing things up. Removed it, now it works.

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1